# redshift revoke privlage from super_user

Tags: aws, redshift

I had created a redshift cluster with a dbuser named :- `ateam` (super_user)
Now I have manually created a db user named :- `bteam` (new super_user)

How can I revoke super_user privilege from `ateam` and grant only "Select" privileges to `ateam`.

I read documentations in aws and read other answers in stackoverflow but was unable to do that. Hence asking the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

> A database superuser bypasses all permission checks. Be very careful
>   when using a superuser role. We recommend that you do most of your
>   work as a role that is not a superuser. **Superusers retain all
>   privileges regardless of GRANT and REVOKE commands.**

Comment: thanks @CalZ for replying,
but is there any work around available could i delete this super user and create a new user with same name with only limited privalge would it work

Comment: I haven't tried and don't see other deleting the initial superuser, as that's something you have to setup when defining very basic properties of the cluster. Why exactly do you need to do this? If someone has the password for it that shouldn't, how about changing the password?